# Pandas: Convert Month Name to Int + Concat to Column and Convert to Date time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, calendar

1. Convert Month Name (ex.October) to int value.
2. Append this column "Month" to the beginning of another column "FY"
3. Convert new column "Month FY" to date

I've tried to used pandas, calendar, datetime, but have been unsuccessful.  I would like to accomplish this without having to create a dict.

End Goal: 
Month FY
10/1/2018

What I've tried:

```
var2.Month = var2.Month.astype('|S')
pd.to_datetime(var2.Month)
var2['Month'] = var2['Month'].apply(lambda x: cal.month_abbr[x])
var2.Month = datetime.datetime.strptime(var2.Month, "%m")
pd.to_datetime(var2.Month, format='%b').dt.month
```

Comment: One comment: ``pd.to_datetime`` is not an in-place operation. It returns a converted column, and you should probably store that result somewhere.

Comment: What? Your objective is to convert the month to a number, but your code with the `apply` does the opposite?

Answer (score 3):

```
df['yy'] = df['fy'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('FY '))

df['yy'] = pd.to_datetime(df.yy,format='%Y').dt.year

df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.month, format='%B').dt.month
```